# While loop in python for multiple conditions

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am generating a sentence from a list of words with interspersed random characters. Below already answers the question but I would like the sentences to be between length 27 characters to 31 characters. I did try to play around with the while loop multiple conditions but it generates more than 32 character sentences.

Also, the below has the interspersed characters to be of 5 characters in length how do I edit it to be either 5 or 10 characters so that the overall length of the sentence can be between 27-31 characters and print only those combinations to a textfile?

```
import random
import itertools

words = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'cherry', 'grapes']
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

def combinations(words):
   options = set()
   for perm in list(itertools.permutations(words)):
      s = perm[0]
      i = 1
      while len(s) < 31 or len(s) >27 and i < len(perm):
           s += ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(5))
           s += perm[i]
           i += 1
      options.add(s)
  return options
print(combinations(words))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Definitely fix the indentation. I'm having trouble telling where it's an indentation issue and where it's a logic issue. I definitely see why part of your loop isn't working the way you think it should, but I can't tell how to fix it while trying to read around the indentation.

Comment: fixed the indentation